# Render observable in component while waiting for next value?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a scenario were certain data may need to be refreshed on the server, but is a long running task.

What i need is to get the current state of the data and render it while I wait for the refreshed data from the server. I have a component that will render the obserable, while sending another call to refresh it. my getData service method looks like the following sudo code (creates a behavior subject with a false initial value, and then emits true to do the refresh)

```
behaviorsubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);

data$ = behaviorsubject.pipe(
  refresh => swichMap(httpclientcall?refresh=${refresh})
  .pipe(
    tap(res => {
     if(res.needsRefresh) behaviorsubject.next(true)
  })
)
return data$
```

This sort of works. However, my page does not render until the second http call is returned. In my componet, I use the following to determine if the component will render. I see the spinner until the refresh call completes.

```
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data; else spinner">
```

The desired result

```
Component after inital http call:
Data from server: (status loading)

Component after refresh http call:
Data from server: up-to-date
```

What is the best way to have the first call in the observable complete so the component can render without waiting for the second. Hopefully I explained this well enough.

Comment: How is data$ linked to the call? Please add code for that.

Comment: Just send the initial call then setup the refresh logic, this way you are debouncing the first request as well.

Comment: data$ = behaviorsubject.pipe(.... data$ is returned from the getData service call

Comment: Ive tried wrapping the if(needsRefresh) logic in a setTimeout. This works, i just dont know if tis the righ way to do this in rxjs or if there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) to return an observable that has two sources that emit independently into the same stream.

In this case, you don't even need to use a subject:

```js
data$ = http.get(url_1).pipe(
  switchMap(response1 => { 
    const call1 = of(response1);
    const call2 = response1.needsRefresh ? http.get(url_2) : EMPTY;

    return merge(call1, call2);
  })
)
```